# Navigation in home page is not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have navigated from login page to home page.In home page,if i click questions,questionsnew or what ever link the corresponding page is not showing
inside the home page(http://localhost/home).

Here is my all code snippets

app.module.ts

```
var myroutes:Routes=[
{path:"",redirectTo:"home",pathMatch:"full"},
{path:"home",component:HomeComponent},
{path: 'userdetails',component:UserdetailsComponent},
{path:'questions',component:QuestionsIndexComponent},
{path:'questionsnew',component:QuestionsNewComponent  },
{path:'questionsview',component:QuestionsViewComponent},
{path:'FancyButtons',component:FancybuttonsComponent}];
var allroutes=RouterModule.forRoot(myroutes);
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.component.html

```
<div id="appdesign" align="center" *ngIf="showButton">
  <br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <h1>MY FIRST PROJECT IN ANGULAR2</h1>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

 <h4>Existing Users can: </h4>
  <button style="height: 25px;width:50px" routerLink="/login" (click)="btnloginclick()">Login</button>
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <h4>New User can:</h4>     
<button style="height: 25px;width:50px" routerLink="/register">Register</button>
</div>    
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.html

```
<div id="logindiv">
  <h4>Login</h4>
<form #myloginform="ngForm">
Email : <input type="text"[(ngModel)]="email" required="required" #ctrlemail="ngModel"  name="email" ><br>
<span class="error" *ngIf="ctrlemail.invalid && ctrlemail.touched && ctrlemail.errors.required">EMAIL CANT BE BLANK</span>
Password: <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password"  ><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" (click)="onLoginClick(myloginform)"><br>
  {‌{message}}
</form>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
onLoginClick(myloginform)
{
if (myloginform.valid==true)
{
    this.objroute.navigate(['home']);
}
```

Home.component.html

```
<div id="header">
  <br>
<a routerLink="userdetails" routerLinkActive="active">UserDetails</a>&nbsp;    
  <a routerLink="questions">Questions</a>&nbsp;
  <a routerLink="questionsnew">New Question</a>&nbsp;
  <a routerLink="questionsview">View Question</a>&nbsp;
  <a routerLink="FancyButtons">Fancy Buttons</a>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="pagecontent">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Please identify my issue and provide me correct solution,so that i could proceed with my sample project.

Thanks

Rajula

Comment: check the console is it throwing any error ?

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/questions'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/questions'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because the url you are trying to navigate to does not exist try it like this

```
<a routerLink="../questions">Questions</a>&nbsp;
  <a routerLink="../questionsnew">New Question</a>&nbsp;
  <a routerLink="../questionsview">View Question</a>&nbsp;
  <a routerLink="../FancyButtons">Fancy Buttons</a>
```

Comment: i have given url in app.module.ts as routes

Comment: what do you mean by _i have given url in app.module.ts as routes_

Comment: Route navigation for pages are given in app,module.ts

Comment: yes i know that but the url you declared and the url that you are trying to access are not the same you declared `'questions'` url and trying to access `'home/questions'`

Comment: wow,if i change routes like this in app.module,{path:'home/questions',component:QuestionsIndexComponent},   
  {path:'home/questionsnew',component:QuestionsNewComponent},
  {path:'home/questionsview',component:QuestionsViewComponent},

Comment: but for children of home, {path:"",component:HomeComponent,children:
   [
     { path:'home/home/register',component:RegisterComponent,
     { path:'home/home/categories',component:CategoriesComponent,    
     },     {path:'home/home/contact',component:ContactComponent}
   ]   
  }, first time it loads as home/home/contact.Next if i click other route like register , it throws error as Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/home/contact'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting pages inside new component, LayoutComponent as children:

```
{path:"",component: LayoutComponent, children: [
 {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home'},
 {path:"home",component:HomeComponent}
 {path: 'userdetails',component:UserdetailsComponent},
 {path:'questions',component:QuestionsIndexComponent},
 {path:'questionsnew',component:QuestionsNewComponent  },
 {path:'questionsview',component:QuestionsViewComponent},
 {path:'FancyButtons',component:FancybuttonsComponent}
]}
```

So, create a Layout component, place router-outlet inside of it, and do routing like this.

Comment: when i place register link as children of home component, it throws this :ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/home/register'

Comment: add / before routes @rajula in your html/ts, example:  routerLink="/questions"

Comment: Is it correct way to place router-outlet in app.component and also in home.html

Comment: @rajula yes it is, because in home component, if you have children routes, router outlet will display only those routes, and all others inside the app component

Comment: whatever link i clicked, by default it adds 'home' to it
eg:-if i click 'questions' then 
error is: could not match routes
'home/questions'
if i click 'register' then 
error is: could not match routes
'home/home/%2Fregister'

Comment: Try changing the structure, add a new component and nest everything inside it. @rajula